# Create collection of bitwise matches from an integer range

Tags: perl, binary, openvswitch

[The OVS documentation](http://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-fields.7.txt)

... describes populating rules in the following format:

> Range matches can be expressed as a collection of bitwise matches. For
>   example, suppose that the goal is  to  match TCP source ports 1000 to
>   1999, inclusive. The binary representations of 1000 and 1999 are:

```
01111101000
11111001111
```

> The following series of bitwise matches will  match  1000 and 1999 and
>   all the values in between:

```
01111101xxx
0111111xxxx
10xxxxxxxxx
110xxxxxxxx
1110xxxxxxx
11110xxxxxx
1111100xxxx
```

> which can be written as the following matches:

```
tcp,tp_src=0x03e8/0xfff8
tcp,tp_src=0x03f0/0xfff0
tcp,tp_src=0x0400/0xfe00
tcp,tp_src=0x0600/0xff00
tcp,tp_src=0x0700/0xff80
tcp,tp_src=0x0780/0xffc0
tcp,tp_src=0x07c0/0xfff0
```

I'm trying to determine the correct way to generate those matches based on a minimum and maximum integer value in perl. I looked at the module Bit::Vector , but I wasn't able to figure out how to effectively use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's pretend we trying to solve the equivalent problem for decimal for a second.

Say you want 567 (inclusive) to 1203 (exclusive).

1. Enlarging phase

   1. You increment by 1 until you have the a multiple of 10 or you would exceed the range.

      1. ⇒598 (Creates 597-597)
      2. ⇒599 (Creates 598-598)
      3. ⇒600 (Creates 599-599)
   2. You increment by 10 until you have a multiple of 100 or you would exceed the range.
   3. You increment by 100 until you have a multiple of 1000 or you would exceed the range.

      1. ⇒700 (Creates 600-699)
      2. ⇒800 (Creates 700-799)
      3. ⇒900 (Creates 800-899)
      4. ⇒1000 (Creates 900-999)
   4. You increment by 1000 until you have a multiple of 10000 or you would exceed the range.

      1. [Would exceed limit]
2. Shrinking phase

   1. You increment by 100 until you would exceed the range.

      1. ⇒1100 (Creates 1000-1099)
      2. ⇒1200 (Creates 1100-1199)
   2. You increment by 10 until you would exceed the range.
   3. You increment by 1 until you would exceed the range.

      1. ⇒1201 (Creates 1200-1200)
      2. ⇒1202 (Creates 1201-1201)
      3. ⇒1203 (Creates 1202-1202)

Same in binary, but with powers of 2 instead of powers of 10.

```
my $start = 1000;
my $end   = 1999 + 1;

my @ranges;

my $this = $start;
my $this_power = 1;
OUTER: while (1) {
   my $next_power = $this_power * 2;
   while ($this % $next_power) {
      my $next = $this + $this_power;
      last OUTER if $next > $end;

      my $mask = ~($this_power - 1) & 0xFFFF;
      push @ranges, sprintf("0x%04x/0x%x", $this, $mask);
      $this = $next;
   }

   $this_power = $next_power;
}

while ($this_power > 1) {
   $this_power /= 2;
   while (1) {
      my $next = $this + $this_power;
      last if $next > $end;

      my $mask = ~($this_power - 1) & 0xFFFF;
      push @ranges, sprintf("0x%04x/0x%x", $this, $mask);
      $this = $next;
   }
}

say for @ranges;
```

We can optimize that by taking advantage of the fact that we're dealing with binary.

```
my $start = 1000;
my $end   = 1999 + 1;

my @ranges;

my $this = $start;
my $power = 1;
my $mask = 0xFFFF;
while ($start & $mask) {
   if ($this & $power) {
      push @ranges, sprintf("0x%04x/0x%x", $this, $mask);
      $this += $power;
   }

   $mask &= ~$power;
   $power <<= 1;
}

while ($end & ~$mask) {
   $power >>= 1;
   $mask |= $power;

   if ($end & $power) {
      push @ranges, sprintf("0x%04x/0x%x", $this, $mask);
      $this |= $power;
   }
}

say for @ranges;
```

Output:

```
0x03e8/0xfff8
0x03f0/0xfff0
0x0400/0xfe00
0x0600/0xff00
0x0700/0xff80
0x0780/0xffc0
0x07c0/0xfff0
```

Answer (score -1):

I attempted to use the very elegant solution provided by @ikegami but found there were edge cases with resulting ports outside of the range or missing ports (e.g. 1-6, 1000-4000, 1000-10000). This alternative approach seems to avoid these issues.

```perl
my $LIMIT = 65535;

sub maxPort {
    my ($port, $mask) = @_;

    my $xid = $LIMIT - $mask;
    my $nid = $port & $mask;
    return $nid + $xid;
}

sub portMask {
    my ($port, $end) = @_;

    my $mask = $LIMIT;
    my $test_mask = $LIMIT;
    my $bit = 1;
    my $net = $port & $LIMIT;
    my $max_port = maxPort($net, $LIMIT);

    while ($net && ($max_port <= $end)) {
        $net = $port & $test_mask;
        if ($net < $port) {
            last;
        }
        $max_port = maxPort($net, $test_mask);
        if ($max_port <= $end) {
            $mask = $test_mask;
        }
        $test_mask -= $bit;
        $bit <<= 1;
    }

    return $mask;
}

sub maskRange {
    my ($start, $end) = @_;

    my @portMasks;

    if (($end <= $start) || ($end > $LIMIT)) {
        exit 1;
    }

    my $mask = $LIMIT;
    my $port = $start;

    while ($port <= $end) {
        $mask = portMask($port, $end);
        push @portMasks, sprintf("0x%04x/0x%x", $port, $mask);
        $port = maxPort($port, $mask) + 1;
    }

    return @portMasks;
}

my @ranges = maskRange(1000, 1999);

for (@ranges) {
    print("$_", "\n");
}
```

Outputs:

```
0x03e8/0xfff8
0x03f0/0xfff0
0x0400/0xfe00
0x0600/0xff00
0x0700/0xff80
0x0780/0xffc0
0x07c0/0xfff0
```